# Align text with url in the same line

Tags: lightning-web-components, url

I'm trying to align the text with the  url both inside span tags, don't know why the alignment stopped working when I started using the url as second element, any ideas?

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default"> 
        <lightning-accordion class="example-accordion" 
        onsectiontoggle={handleToggleSection}
        allow-multiple-sections-open>
            <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label="Adobe LWC" class="label">
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-list_horizontal">
                    <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-medium-size_1-of-2 slds-large-size_1-of-2">
                        <div>
                            <span>Page Name:</span>
                            <span><p></p><lightning-formatted-url value={sfdcBaseURL} label={adobeSummaryModel.PageNameCount} target="_blank"></lightning-formatted-url></p></span>
                        </div>                                              
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </lightning-accordion-section>
        </lightning-accordion>
    </div>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: No need to add multiple spans just place those two elements directly in the parent div. Also, remove the p tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Horizontal alignment can be achieved using the slds class `slds-grid` on the wrapping parent div.  either remove your extra ‘div’ tag or add this class to it.

This will work:

```
  <div class="slds-grid">
       <span>Page Name:</span>
       <span><p></p><lightning-formatted-url value={sfdcBaseURL} label={adobeSummaryModel.PageNameCount} target="_blank"></lightning-formatted-url></p></span>
 </div>
```